# Merging two files and ordering them

Tags: sorting, awk

I want to merge two files in one and order them based on the values of the second column. The example is the following:

File 1:

```
+ 1.01 id 120
- 1.20 id 145
+ 2.15 id 411
(continues)
```

File 2:

```
r 0.21 id 4
r 1.78 id 85
r 102 id 850
(continues)
```

I want to merge them in one file but I would like to put them in ascending order based on the column 2 like this:

File 3:

```
r 0.21 id 4
+ 1.01 id 120
- 1.20 id 145
r 1.78 id 85
+ 2.15 id 411
r 102 id 850
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about

```
sort -k2n file1 file2
```

`f1` and `f2` are your files:

```
kent$ sort -k2n f1 f2
r 0.21 id 4
+ 1.01 id 120
- 1.20 id 145
r 1.78 id 85
+ 2.15 id 411
r 102 id 850
```